# How can I merge multiple dictionaries and add the values of the same key? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

Suppose I have the following dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'c': 4}
dict3 = {'e':9, 'a':3}
```

I'm trying to merge them in a way such that the new (combinational) dictionary contains all the keys and all the values of the same key are added together. For instance, in this case, my desired output looks like:

```
dict = {'a': 13, 'b': 8, 'c':7, 'e':9}
```

It looks like the update() method doesn't work since some values are overwritten. I also tried ChainMaps and encountered the same issue. How can I merge multiple dictionaries and add the values of the same key?Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a *dictionary comprehension* to achieve this using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). Here, I am creating a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of keys from all the three dicts. Then I am iteration over this set inside *dictionary comprehension* to get the sum of *values* per *key*.

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':3}
>>> dict2 = {'c': 4}
>>> dict3 = {'e':9, 'a':3}

>>> my_dicts = dict1, dict2, dict3

>>> {k: sum(dd.get(k, 0) for dd in my_dicts) for k in set(chain.from_iterable(d.keys() for d in my_dicts))}
{'a': 13, 'e': 9, 'b': 8, 'c': 7}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helps a lot:)

Comment: @Zhengrong if this answer helped you, you can also upvote it by clicking up arrow on the left. It will help me with 10 additional reputation gain

Answer (score 0):

This code below should do the trick:

```
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 8, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'c': 4}
dict3 = {'e':9, 'a':3}

multiple_dict = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

final_dict = {}

for dict in multiple_dict:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if key in final_dict:
            final_dict[key] += value
        else:
            final_dict[key] = value

print(final_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you!! That's very helpful:)